# Problem with recording data change in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two sheets. On one sheet (Sheet1), I have a column 'A' which has 5 fixed values, and a column 'B' which records the timestamp value in 'A' change. The other sheet (Sheet2) is meant to record all the changes in the first sheet in one day.

I use this simple query in the recording sheet:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A$1:X,"select * where C>="& Sheet2!D1)
```

with Sheet1!C has timestamps and Sheet2!D1 is the timestamp of 12:00 AM today

The problem is when I change the value of a row in C columns more than one time, instead of creating a new row in Sheet2 it change the value of that row in Sheet2 into new values.

So how do I change my code to get my desire results?
[image: sheet1 data]

[image: desired output]

EDIT 2: here is my new code, but it doesn't help.

```
function importdata(x) {
  // var row = x.range.getRow();
  // var col = x.range.getColumn();

  var addedsheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Change"); // Sheet where I want to keep the record of the change
  var original_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Master"); //sheet where the change is happended
  var compared_value = addedsheet.getRange(1,4).getValue(); // Cell D1 of sheet "Change", which has timestamp of today

  var insert_area = original_sheet.getRange("A2:X").getValues() // area to get value from "Master" sheet to put into "Change"

  var compared_area = original_sheet.getRange("C2:C").getValues(); // area where has timestamp

  if (compared_area >= compared_value){
    
    addedsheet.values.append([insert_area])}

} //if timestamp of one row from Master is greater than the value at Change!D1 =>append that row at the end (this is what I'm trying to do)
```

EDIT 3: I fixed the above code by append[insert_area][0] instead of [insert_area]
But then I have a new problem: there will a chance that a row in sheet 1 will be overwrited in sheet 2. I try something like this, but it returns nothing on the sheet.

```
function for_each_row(){
 var addedsheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Change"); // Sheet where I want to keep the record of the change
  var original_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Master"); //sheet where the change is happended
  var compared_value = addedsheet.getRange(1,4).getValue(); // Cell D1 of sheet "Change", which has timestamp of today
  var number_of_row_2 = addedsheet.getLastRow;
  var number_of_row_1 = original_sheet.getLastRow();


  for (var i=2; i<number_of_row_1 +1; i++){
    var compared_stamp = original_sheet.getRange("C"+i).getValues(); 
    var insert_values = (original_sheet.getRange(i,1,1,24).getValues())
    if (compared_stamp > compared_value){ 
      
      var insert_values = (original_sheet.getRange(i,1,1,24).getValues()); 
      for (var j = 2; j<number_of_row_2 +1; j++){ 
      
       var value_from_sheet = addedsheet.getRange(j,1,1,24).getValues(); 
      
       
       if (insert_values ===value_from_sheet){ 
         
         return 
       }
       else(
       addedsheet.appendRow(insert_values[0])) 
       

    }
  }
  }
 }
```

My thought is if a row satisfies the 1st condition then the value will be check in sheet 2. If sheet 2 didn't have that row then append that row.

Comment: Can you provide a copy of your spreadsheet, clearly indicating the desired output?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to record all date/time changes against a fixed value, referring to the date/time in Sheet1!C:C, that are from today and onwards? If you're going to overwrite the values in Sheet1!C:C, then you'll only get the latest value pulled through to Sheet2. If you keep all changes in Sheet1, then Sheet2 will display all changes against your fixed value.

Comment: I have added the picture, hope it make sense.

to Aresvik: so how can I record all the change of sheet 1 into sheet 2 without keeping the record of change in sheet 1?

Comment: I think this could be accomplished with an Apps Script [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger. Are you open to using that?

Comment: yes, I can; just do not know how to do

Comment: I added my code above, you can check it.

Comment: What should cause the rows to be appended? When a specific cell or row is edited? Can you please clarify what would that be?

Comment: 1st condition: the value at the C cell > a certain value in another Sheet.
2nd condition: the row isn't already in that another Sheet.
if both 1st and 2nd conditions are satisfied then append.

Comment: I'm not sure I made myself clear. My point was _what should trigger this function?_. An `onEdit` trigger executes every time a spreadsheet is edited by a user, so it would be useful for the function to check which cell was edited, and stop execution if the edited cell is not a relevant one. For example, it could check if the edited cell is in column C of sheet 1. Also, when you say `the row isn't already in that another Sheet`, how would you know that's the case? What's the criteria to identify which rows are the same or not? The value from a specific column. Consider clarifying all this.

Comment: Sorry for not making myself clear, I'm quite new to function and just knew that onEdit has trigger. My plan is when people create change in sheet then the function will activate => basically, I will use onEdit function.

"the row isn't already in that another Sheet" => I run a loop to compare the value of any row which satisfies the 1st condition to all the rows in sheet 2. If a single value in a row is different then I will consider it's a new row and I want to append it to Sheet 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

If I understand you correctly, you want to do the following:

- If sheet `Master` is edited, iterate through all rows in this sheet (excluding headers), and for each row, check the following:

  1. Column `C` has a higher value than cell `D1` in sheet `Change`.
  2. This row, with these exact values, does not exist in `Change`.
- If these conditions are meet, append the row to `Change`.

#### Solution:

Use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to filter out rows that don't match your two conditions, and use [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) to write the resulting rows to your other sheet.

#### Code snippet:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var editedSheet = e ? e.range.getSheet() : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (editedSheet.getName() === "Master") {
    var addedSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Change");
    var compared_value = addedSheet.getRange(1,4).getValue();
    var newData = editedSheet.getRange("A2:X" + editedSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var currentData = addedSheet.getRange("A2:X" + addedSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var filteredData = newData.filter(row => row[2] >= compared_value)
                              .filter(row => !currentData.some(currentRow => JSON.stringify(currentRow) === JSON.stringify(row)));
    addedSheet.getRange(addedSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,filteredData.length,filteredData[0].length).setValues(filteredData);
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- An easy way to check if two rows have the same values is using [JSON.stringify(row)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).
- I'm assuming the `timestamps` are not [Dates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). If they are, you should compare them using [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime). So you should change the corresponding code to `newData.filter(row => row[2].getTime() >= compared_value.getTime())`.